# How to stagger bullet charts using nvd3 , d3, javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to produce 5 bullet charts stacked on top of each other such as in this example: 
http://boothead.github.com/d3/ex/bullet.html

I'm using the d3 and nvd3 packages for the charts.  How can I iterate through and translate each chart further down the page?  My working code is:

```
for (var i =0; i<5;i++){

  nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.bulletChart();
    d3.select('#chart svg') 
      .append("svg:g")
      .datum(exampleData())
      .transition().duration(1000)
      .call(chart);
      return chart;
  }); 
}
```

but this just stacks all the charts right on top of each other.

I've tried using .attr("transform", "translate(0,"+i*50+")") after appending svg:g element and also doing something afterwards such as,

```
d3.selectAll("svg:g").attr("transform", function(i){ return "translate(0,"+i*50+")" });
```

I can't seem to get a counter variable in scope or for some reason it isn't displaying properly.  Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: why not use multiple svg's ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? Would love to see an example if you did

Answer (score 1):

Two things to check:

- use `d3.selectAll` to get all svg nodes
- your `transform` function needs to take two parameters as in `function(d,i) {...}`. `d` refers to the data being processed, `i` is the index you want to use for displacement